# Beanstalk/Node.Js/Network Issue

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-web-services, network-programming

We are running a node API application on Elastic Beanstalk, and are using Dynamo for a DB, and Redis in Elastic Cache. I'm loading testing, by running a loop of request calls against the node API, simulating about 20,000 simultaneous users making calls.

It runs fine for a while. It gets up to just over 30,000 total calls. Then I start not being able to connect to dynamo and redis. I get the following:

"Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the`us-west-2' region.\",\"code\":\"UnknownEndpoint\",\"stack\":\"UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'."

"Redis connection to xxxxxx-lt-001.19atpm.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

But it's already been running quite happily for quite a while at that point.

I see around 20,000/30,000 connections on the app server. I see a response time of less than 200 ms for my calls up to that point, and all of a sudden they jump in length, getting steadily longer and longer. I have upped the open file count on the app server to 100,000, and the max connections for node to 50,000.

The app server is a C4.xlarge. CPU is not hitting 30%. Neither Dynamo nor Redis are near their limits, far from it. Network out peaks at 40,000,000, Network in peaks at 100,000,000.

I'm now completely stumped. Any suggestions?

/etc/security/limits.conf file:

- soft    nofile          100000
- hard    nofile          100000

Results of ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59742
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 59742
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

**Bit more info** - I found some errors in the messages log about "nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet." So I followed the suggestions in the following web page to increase the size of the table. That got me further, up to 45,000 or so calls. Then it really fell off the table. Went immediately from subsecond response time to 25 second response time.

http://www.mwclearning.com/?p=1506

Comment: we can likely use more code, all relevant config files & etc

Comment: Not exactly sure what to show you. It's an express app, to show you the entire app would be a lot of code. It's a framework we have used successfully many times, without this problem.

Comment: Added a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that in this case, a couple of smaller boxes, will use up their CPU before causing the network to explode. The c4.xlarge did not. Part of that may be the poor way that node clustering works in versions before v 12 of node, where the round robin did not use all the CPUs equally.

Comment: can you please add bit more info, I am facing similar issue.
I am using `ELB` and `ec2` `c3` machine

Comment: I have another ticket in with Amazon on this now, as this morning, a small app that we have that has almost no traffic started getting this error. So now I'm confused. The smaller boxes do seem more effecient, and were able to run at 50 percent CPU for four hours under load. The bigger box was hitting only about 35% CPU before I started getting errors on it. I also filed a bug with the dynamo document sdk owner, asking if they were reporting spurious network errors. That's about all I have for now.

Comment: @CargoMeister Could you update when you have answers from AWS? I'm getting the same error for DynamoDB and S3, and this only happens in us-west-2 region. Thanks!